# Why is my iron ore disappearing when mined with a wooden pickaxe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on Peaceful mode, and I am using a Wooden Pickaxe. Whenever I mine Iron Ore, it just disappears. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I assumed the question was about Minecraft, not Skyrim, and changed the tags accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I mine diamond and gold ore?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/why-cant-i-mine-diamond-and-gold-ore)

Comment: @JohntheGreen While it would be nice to have a canonical "why is my ore disappearing when I mine?" question, this isn't a duplicate of a question that asks why can't one mine diamond and gold ore.

Comment: Mark an answer as correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 44):

Wooden picks aren't strong enough to mine iron, you need at least a stone pick to do that. [All you ever wanted to know about picks.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe)

Answer (score 10):

Wooden Pick cannot mine Iron Ore. Use it to mine stone, then craft the stone into a stone pick. A stone pick can be used to mine Iron Ore.

Answer (score 8):

If you make a wood pick first and mine some stone then you can make a stone pick. A stone pick can be used to mine Iron and Lapis Lazuli ore.

Mine some iron ore with your stone pick. Smelt the ore in a furnace and use the iron ingots to make an iron pick. Iron picks can be used to to mine Diamonds, Gold and Redstone.

A Diamond pick can be used to mine Obsidian.

Answer (score 1):

Wooden pickaxes aren't the best for iron ore. Instead you need to mine 3 stone blocks, craft them into a stone pickaxe in the crafting table, then you can mine the iron ore with the pickaxe. Depending on the type of pickaxe, it's best to use an improved pickaxe for the rare ores, such as an iron pickaxe, which is required by smelting the iron ore in a furnace into ingots. If you have 3 or more, craft it into an iron pickaxe to mine rare ores. Diamonds pickaxes are used to mine obsidian, but I will act like you're using your hand to punch stone, so it's best if they're enchanted.

Answer (score 0):

A wooden pickaxe cannot mine Iron. The only ore woodden pickaxes can mine is coal. You need a stone, iron or diamond pickaxe to be able to get iron. Here's how to get iron:

1. Use your sticks and cobblestone to craft a stone pickaxe.
2. Use your stone pickaxe to mine iron ore.

Comment: Actually, the wooden pickaxe can also mine Nether quartz as well.