# I can't mine gold, diamonds, redstone, nothing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using a wooden pickaxe, and that might be the problem, I can mine coal and flint, but nothing else. Can someone help please?

(edit) I was using nothing to mine down a staircase, when I stumbled upon a cave, keep in mind this is in single player. And I cannot mine the diamonds, the redstone, the gold, nothing. it just doesn't give it to me. can someone please help me understand why this is happening? I just can't get it to work. I want my gold...

Comment: See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/why-is-my-iron-ore-disappearing-when-mined-with-a-wooden-pickaxe

Comment: It should have taken some time to reach diamonds with a wooden pick to test that out...

Answer (score 2):

You answer your own question. A wooden pickaxe cannot mine these minerals.

See [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tools) for information about which tools can harvest which minerals.