# Why can't I mine Iron Ore in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I'm playing Minecraft and try to mine iron ore, it breaks into pieces. But then, there aren't any blocks on the ground to pick up. I don't have any problems with picking up stone blocks and wood, and I can even pick up coal. I am using a pickaxe and I don't have the same problem in my other worlds. Is there a problem with my settings?

Comment: Are you referring to iron ore?

Comment: Wait, what pickaxe are you using? If you’re using a wooden or golden (which kinda sucks) pickaxe, you cannot mine iron. Stone, iron, diamond, and netherite pickaxes can.

Answer (score 7):

Minecraft doesn't have a "tutorial", exactly, so it is difficult to understand the rules, the first time you play. If you visit the wiki however, you can find out a lot about the game.

In this instance, you'll find that in order to mine [Iron Ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore), you need a Stone Pick. A Wooden one will not work.

Comment: i say tutorial is considered with "Advancements" but in the edu. edition of minecraft, there is a full fledged tutorial which is prebuilt in the copy. He could simply follow the advancements and he'd understand a few more things about Minecraft

Answer (score 1):

There are [certain tiers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxecertain) of pickaxes (wooden, stone, iron, ...). If the iron ore breaks without dropping something, you are probably using a wooden pickaxe. A wooden pickaxe only works on stone and coal blocks.
Try to use a stone pickaxe (same way to construct it, but with cobblestone instead of planks. You will see the iron ore will drop and you can pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has also asked this question and you can find it here: [Why is my iron ore disappearing when mined with a wooden pickaxe?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/why-is-my-iron-ore-disappearing-when-mined-with-a-wooden-pickaxe).

From what they said from the question, the simplest advice I can give you is that you need a stone pickaxe or greater to mine iron ore.