# Mining Diamonds in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

After trying to mine a diamond vein for his ores, I get my pickaxe broken, lost the vein of diamond and didn't get any ore.

I was using a **iron pickaxe** to do the mining. Could the type of the pickaxe influence in this matter? Which one should I use to mine diamond vein?

PS: My pickaxe durability was full, I haven't used it before.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Please give a good vote not a bad one really trying to get a reputation and badges

Comment: @I'mthecoolguy: Writing good (ie. well-formulated, not-easily googled) questions on popular topics (minecraft is a good choice) will help you get reputation and badges. Writing bad questions will not.

Comment: @I'mthecoolguy I reformulated your question. I just wanna know if now it's still the droid that you are looking for.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you were mining **diamonds** with an **iron** pick, and then you didn't get the diamonds when you mined them with the iron pick? Right?

Comment: Cleaned up some comments - let's keep it friendly, guys.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Why can't I mine diamond gold or redstone ore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/why-cant-i-mine-diamond-gold-ore-or-redstone-ore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iron pickaxe is fine for picking up diamond ore.
So using your iron pickaxe for diamonds should work.

Have a look at this table :

[Pickaxes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pickaxe)

Even if the pickaxe loses it's durability you can take the next one and you will never ever lose ore for that. Either you pick it or you don't. Sometimes it happens that after mining the ore falls down into lava or water but that's it.