# In Minecraft (pocket edition for iPad), mining red stone and gold it wont give me redstone or gold. It just destroys it

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm in a cave and when I mine for redstone and gold it destroys it, but it won't let me pick it up. I'm using a stone pick axe and I'm on the pocket edition for iPad in survival mode. I'm playing it with my sister.

Comment: The stone pick is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a stone pick isn't a high enough quality to mine redstone and gold. You can mine iron ore on the other hand, and smelt iron ore with coal or any wooden object really, and make an iron pick to mine redstone and gold (and all ores and blocks except obsidian, which you need a diamond pick for)

[Link to the question which was previously answered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/why-cant-i-mine-diamond-gold-ore-or-redstone-ore)